# Android Volley Post Request - Cant parse response?

Tags: android, json, android-volley

For some reason I can't get this to work. If I try on other testing sites like reqbin the request should work and returns the data in the proper format.

Here is the android code:

```
System.out.println("VOLLEY POST");

    String postUrl = "***MY LOGIN URL***";
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    JSONObject postData = new JSONObject();
    try {
        postData.put("email", "test@email.dk");
        postData.put("password", "abc123");

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, postUrl, postData, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            System.out.println(response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

However, when I try to run it I get this error:

```
com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value <pre of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

When I try to run the exact same request with same parameters on a site like reqbin I get this response (which is in fact valid JSON):

```
  {
    "currency": 97,
    "email": "jeppe@mail.dk",
    "id": 1
}
```

Can anyone help me clarify? Is it something in my Java code that is wrong? I have been really scratching my head on this..

I am brand new to Android programming btw, I come from web/iOS background.

Thanks a lot for reading!

Comment: check data type of email at your pojo class, I guess something wrong there. it should be String type.

Comment: which one in particular are you talking about? I pass the email in as post parameter as a string directly if that is what yo mean? or do you mean from the response? Because that is listed as a string

Comment: I am talking about the response.

Comment: Disregard @AniruddhParihar, there is no pojo class. He wants a simple JSONObject

Comment: It seems like the server is responding with `<pre`... which seems to be html. Perhaps you need to set additional request headers to enforce the response type to be json?

Comment: If you're testing on reqbin: Show us the content of both the "Raw" request and "Raw" response. (Censoring sensitive data of course)